# Consulta Select en database firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase

Tengo la siguiente base de datos en firebase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora quiero traer los titulos de las ciudades dependiendo su numero de zona

He intentado traer el dato y ponerlo en un TextView pero hasta ahora no muestra nada

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = myRef.child("cities");
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot citi : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        txt.setText(citi.getValue().toString());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no se entiende, ¿qué quiere decir  *quiero traer los titulos de las ciudades dependiendo su numero de zona*? Si ofreces un ejemplo concreto de lo que quieres obtener quizá sea más fácil ayudarte. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Recuperamos los "cities" que por ejemplo tengan "zone" en 2. Aqui te dejo una buena pagina para que veas como hacer consultas https://medium.com/android-dev-moz/firebasesql-8bab8efd1e95

```
Long zona_deseada=new Long(2);

DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = myRef.child("cities").orderByChild("zone").equalTo(zona_deseada);
 query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot citi : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    txt.setText(citi.getValue().toString());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```